# SQLSTATE[42S02] Error saying base table or view not found 1146

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, html-table

```
<?php
      $assignmentsTable = $ssubjectnamewithoutspace.'_assignments';

        try {
            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT contentID, contentTitle,contentAuthor, contentLink FROM .$assignmentsTable ORDER BY contentID ASC');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                    echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$row['contentLink'].'">'.$row['contentTitle'].'</a></td></tr>';            


            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found 1146 Table
>   'epiz_5453564654654_newdata.$assignmentsTable' doesn't exist

But table exist in database and when I replace `$assignmentsTable` with table name it works...

Comment: You have a `.`. in `FROM .$assignmentsTable` which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Welcome. Also, `$assignmentsTable` will not be parsed/replaced since you're using single quotes `'` in `$stmt = $db->query('SELECT contentID,.....`

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz

Comment: Your answer helped

Comment: That's why it's bad practice to put vars straight into strings.

Comment: Hi @Brian, just a quick heads-up. I believe the Review Queue ask that edits are not made to recently closed questions by third parties unless the edit would stand a good chance of reopening the question. This is because edits during a five-day period are reported to the Reopen Queue, so small edits will deny the OP of a chance to have a substantive edit seen by re-openers. However, if you wish to make edits to closed questions that are over five days old, I believe there is no objection (and FWIW, I'd be in support for educational reasons).

Answer (score 1):

$assignmentsTable is not evaluated in your query.

Try :

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT contentID, contentTitle,contentAuthor, contentLink FROM `'.$assignmentsTable.'` ORDER BY contentID ASC');
```